# Django dynamic number of filter for a objects request

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I do something like this :

```
products_list = Product.objects.all()

for key in keywords:
    products_list = products_list.filter(name__icontains=q)
```

This don't work.

Comment: out of interest; `Product.objects.all()` retrieves ALL products. `products_list.filter(name__icontains=q)` would then filter and return only products satisfying the query, is this the Django way of doing filtered queries, getting all products from the DB into memory then filtering instead of a query specifiying the condition returning only the required data? Just a question.

Comment: Actually, you cannot do that `product = Product.objects.SOMETHING` and reuse product to continue, you should have all the filter in line As the solution down teach us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering the list with several AND statements, and you want OR statements. Try something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
products_list = Product.objects.all()
orq = None    
for key in keywords:
    thisq = Q(name__icontains=q)
    if orq:
        orq = thisq | orq
    else:
        orq = thisq
products_list = products_list.filter(orq)
```

You could probably clean up the above code, but the idea is to create a variable called `orq` that is basically `Q(name__icontains='prod1') | Q(name__icontains='prod2')`.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work `products_list = Product.objects.all()` and then `products_list = products_list.filter(orq)` but I can directly do `products_list = Product.objects.filter(orq)` and I work perfectly :)

Comment: btw, I guess that if I change | with & I can have a AND instead of a OR